# How to run second random vector through tensorflow to compare output distributions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a variational autoencoder design in tensorflow. This particular approach alters the KL divergence part of the loss to remove any dependence on x, (the input data that is). Instead they want to compare (q_phi(z) || p(z)) rather than (q_phi(z|x) || p(z)). I am taking it that I need to run a random normal or uniform vector of the right shape through the trained network, but am having a hard time figuring out how to input it. Here is what I have so far:

```
class EncoderRNN(object):
    def __init__(self, x, n_steps, input_size, output_size,
                 cell_size, num_layers, default_batch_size):
        # ### Data Input ###
        self.x = x
        # self.init_state = init_state
        self.n_steps = n_steps
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.cell_size = cell_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.default_batch_size = default_batch_size

    ...

class VAE(object):
    def __init__(self, time_steps, features, latent_dim, encoder_hidden,
                 decoder_hidden, num_layers, default_batch_size,
                 learning_rate):
        self.time_steps = time_steps
        self.features = features
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.encoder_hidden = encoder_hidden
        self.decoder_hidden = decoder_hidden
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.default_batch_size = default_batch_size
        self.LR = learning_rate

        with tf.name_scope('train_inputs'):
            # ### Multi-D timeseries input ###
            self.x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.time_steps,
                                              self.features])
            ### 1 D timeseries output ###
            self.x_target = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.time_steps, 1])
            self.batch_size = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)

    ...
```

Here is what I am trying to figure out:

```
def build_codec(self):
    self.encoder = EncoderRNN(self.x,
                          self.time_steps,
                          self.features,
                          self.latent_dim,
                          self.encoder_hidden,
                          self.num_layers,
                          self.default_batch_size)
    # ### Output tensors from encoder ###
    self.mu = self.encoder.mu
    self.logvar = self.encoder.logvar

    epsilon = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(self.logvar), name='epsilon')

    std_encoder = tf.exp(0.5 * self.logvar)

    self.z = self.mu + tf.multiply(std_encoder, epsilon)
    # Now I want to do this:
    x_rand = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(self.x))
    q_z = self.encoder(x_rand)
```

I am not quite sure how to get x_rand through the encoder graph.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that I understand the difficulty correctly, there are a couple of way:

1. First is to realize that TensorFlow allows you to feed any tensor, not just a placeholder. So, you can just do `sess.run(..., feed_dict={self.x: x_rand})` to feed your random value into the `self.x` tensor.
2. Second, if you want to produce your random data with a Dataset pipeline. This can be useful if creating the input takes a while and you want to do it in parallel with `sess.run()` call. Then, you would instantiate your model twice. Once with regular `self.x` input and once with input tensor from Dataset iterator. Both models would share the variables (you would need to create them in a variable scope set to share variables) but the operations (nodes in the computation graph) would be different. You can then call `sess.run()` on any of these two models whenever you want.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this. I am in the middle of calculating the loss term and want to use the output from the random vector running through the encoder for one section of the loss, with the data vector being used for other section of the loss term. This is why I am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your difficulty. I don't quite follow this comment as well. Let me try to clarify. Do you want to do something like GAN training? There, the loss is the sum of discriminator outputs on real images and on generator's outputs. The usual approach there is to instantiate two discriminators sharing weights but taking inputs from (1) real images and (2) generator. If so, please explain the problem with instantiating computation twice. If not, please explain what exactly you want to achieve (with a diagram?) and what are the problems with solutions you tried.